# Why should I disable insecure SSH hostkeys if I never plan on using them?

Tags: ssh, hardening, cryptography

A number of articles suggest removing insecure (broken) SSH key types in order to have a more secure server. In practice, if I only connect to the server with secure key types, why should I bother deleting insecure key types? What is a practical attack that can be performed if I do not remove these key types.

From [SSH audit](https://www.ssh-audit.com/hardening_guides.html#ubuntu_18_04_lts):

> Disable the DSA and ECDSA host keys

From [Secure Secure Shell](https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html):

> DSA keys must be exactly 1024 bits so let’s disable that. Number 2 here involves NIST suckage and should be disabled as well.

Comment: This question seems better suited for [security.se].

Comment: I will move it there. Thank you.